# Cross Layer Implementation in Wireless networks in NS2

Tags: tcl, ns2

Aim of the project is to Explore and Implement Cross-Layer Design Techniques to Improve Communication in Wireless Networks
Using NS2. Please provide me with the code in tcl language to implement this

This was the code i ran but i shows error,

```
typeset ns [new Simulator]    

set val(ifq)        Queue
set val(ll)         LL
set val(ifqlen)         50 
set val(mac)        Mac

$ns node-config -llType $val(ll) \
-ifqType $val(ifq) \
-ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
                -macType $val(mac) \

set tracef [open test.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tracef
set namtf [open test.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namtf

proc finish {} {
    global ns tracef namtf
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracef
    close $namtf
    exec nam test.nam &
    exit 0
}
set i 0
set node_($i) [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]

$ns duplex-link $node_($i) $n1 10Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 10Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 10Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n4 10Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link-op $node_($i) $n1 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n2 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 orient right
$ns duplex-link-op $n3 $n4 orient right

set bop0 [new Agent/BOP]
#bop: a new transport layer protocol
$ns attach-agent $node_($i) $bop0  
$bop0 bop-get-mac [$node_($i) set mac_(0)]

set bop4 [new Agent/BOPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n4 $bop4

$ns connect $bop0 $bop4

set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $bop0
$ftp set type_ FTP

$ns at 1.0 "$ftp start"
$ns at 4.0 "$ftp stop"

$ns at 5.0 "finish"

$ns run  here
```

But shows this error
`invalid command name "Agent/BOP" while executing "Agent/BOP create _o105 " invoked from within "catch "$className create $o $args" msg" invoked from within "if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] { if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] { delete $o return "" } global errorInfo error "class $..." (procedure "new" line 3) invoked from within "new Agent/BOP" invoked from within "set bop0 [new Agent/BOP]" (file "amj.tcl" line 43)` . Pls help
It is not running

Comment: You need to tell us the specific error you got.

Also perhaps take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Tcl's error messages tend to say exactly what is wrong, at least as the code sees it. NS2's are a bit more cryptic sometimes (especially the error-info traces) but still usually informative. What the real cause is can need a bit more intuition, but without the actual message (and trace back for preference) it's hard for us to help.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply this was the error i got.  Please check the question i have updated it

Comment: Well that error message suggests that `Agent/BOP` needs to be defined but has not been.  I don't know ns2 so can't tell how/where it should be defined.

Comment: ns2 : AFAIK only a "new Agent" defined in `file.cc` can be set. ..... No unknown Agents are set in the 3000 ns2 ex https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tptvzNOYJWeoA28Vm92sFIl0w1_qMAvi/view?usp=drive_link : `$ grep -n "new Agent" *` ...... Seems that a new **ns** executable which includes BOP must be used.

Comment: @KnudLarsen hello, can you please elaborate , how to fix this error

Comment: Please tell where you got the "BOP idea". The cross-layer info that I know has no word "BOP" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LmiIX4zfOPDjtby1gXyTOLvSE8C2cBuL/view?usp=sharing . ..... Trouble shooting : Add cross-layer C++ code to ns2, and create a new **ns** → ns-new https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=share_link

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you so much for all your help. I truly appreciate it. Would it be possible for you to provide me with the code for implementing cross-layer communication in ns2? Additionally, if you could kindly guide me through the steps to implement it, that would be amazing. I am a beginner in ns2, so your help would mean the world to me. Thank you again for everything.

Comment: Code is included in my link `Cross-Layer-all.tar.gz` . Please also ask about cross-layer at  https://groups.google.com/g/ns-users